# Getting sums by row in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to implement the rowsums solution proposed here [Getting rowSums in a data table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905257/getting-rowsums-in-a-data-table-in-r) .  Basically I want a variable with the sum of top15, top16 and top17 for each row.  This output produces an answer but its clearly not right, I am sure I understand what is happening.

I am looking for a data.table solution - I am running this on millions of cases

```
library( data.table)
d <- structure(list(top15 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), top16 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), top17 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

d[ , tops:=lapply(.SD,sum), .SDcols=c(paste0("top", 15:17))]
```

Comment: For reference: the cited question (and answer) is about col sums not a row sums. I corrected its title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on the Subset of data.table (`.SD`), which can also take care of the `NA` elements with `na.rm`

```
nm1 <- paste0("top", 15:17)
d[, tops := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = nm1]
```

---

Or if there are no `NA` elements, then do `+` with `Reduce`

```
d[, tops := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = nm1]
```